# Can I boot from an external hardrive and then clone from it to my laptop?

Tags: boot, external-hard-drive, clone

I have a laptop and I'd like to clone my old SATA M.2 drive to a NMVe 970 EVO Plus drive. I spotted a problem in that the caddy I bought only supports SATA connections.

Can I put my old system drive into the caddy, go into the BIOS and change to boot from it along side placing the new NMVe into the laptop body and clone to it from the eternal one?

If not then I'll have to buy a new caddy that supports both versions (universal) as I cant clone to new one with this caddy. The NMVe doesn't fit into it.

I also intend to use the old m.2 SATA as a portable device.

Comment: If you're on Windows, it's pretty tough to persuade it to boot from an external drive. i'd be looking for a 'better' caddy.

Comment: You might be able to put the old drive in the external caddy and then clone the drive from Linux booted from a USB stick, assuming you have enough USB ports.

Comment: Clonezilla and others have bootable USB stick versions and may well achieve what you want. Just be 100% certain about what disk you are copying to what.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Ill take some notes :)

Answer (score 0):

To your question yes, you can boot into any external device with few changes in bios,just put your external device in first priority to boot.

for cloning I think you need to find a proper cloning software which supports two device types of device to be cloned, because as of my knowledge cloning can be only done to the identical devices only

Its not a complete answer but yes it will help you though

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Hmm... ive actually cloned a Normal sata drive to a SSD drive, which is in here now. Ive seen videos with free software to clone drives. Ill make a note of what youve said. Thank you

Comment: I voted for you, but it doesnt let me at the moment